# How to find out which features were used frequently by RandomForestClassiferer in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I have several random forest models that work well. Now, I would like to do feature selection based on this models. How do I find out which features were used frequently by a model e.g. RandomForestClassifier in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 2):

Feature importance it is a property of the random forrest classifier.

See an example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the feature Importance of the RF's , don't forget to use the **hierarchical clustering** from **scipy** and plot the **dendograms**..

It will help you find the similar columns..

Comment: You mean in order to not use strongly correlated columns?

Comment: Plotting the dendogram will reveal the similar columns so you can take a sneak peak at them and them do experiments like dropping one of them let say and then re run the model and recur

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [DALEX](https://pbiecek.github.io/DALEX/) package for R. It is designed to specifically investigate the importance of input variables to perhaps otherwise opaque ML algos.